# Sqlalchemy attribute error- Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, sqlalchemy, pydev

I am trying this in my PyDev setup on eclipse:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
```

This gives me following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<username>/Documents/workspace/You/src/Ormtest.py", line 7, in <module>
    import sqlalchemy
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-intel/egg/sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    # For license information, see LICENSE.TXT
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 39, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from nltk.data              import load
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 106, in <module>
    from decorators import decorator, memoize
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/decorators.py", line 176, in <module>
    @decorator
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/decorators.py", line 154, in decorator
    if inspect.isclass(caller):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'isclass'
```

This works fine on the interactive console. Also Eclipse does not give me any error/warning on import. Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: that exception is occurring deep within nltk, the natural language toolkit, which has nothing to do with SQLAlchemy and is not a dependency, so it seems like PyDev is injecting some weird thing in there.  This looks like some kind of bug in PyDev, I'd report it to them.

Comment: Or it might be related just to NLTK by itself, they have a package named "tokenize" that's getting mistaken for the Python "tokenize" module.  Seems weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing the following to diagnose it: In the line that gives the error do:

```
import sys
print('\n'.join(sorted(sys.path))) #to know which pythonpath you're using
```

My guess is that you added "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk" to your PYTHONPATH (whereas you probably should only add "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages")

Comment: This seems to have solved the problem. Removing nltk and adding just site-packages have resolved the issue for now. Thanks for this. I will get back to you in case any problem arises again :)